# How do I make my html gif unloop?

Tags: html

For the website I have which you can view here http://renegades.netne.net/
You can't see it yet but under the "Code your bot to the next level"
There is a gif there that loops

```
<header id="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="header-text">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h3 class="light white">Ready for Robotics?</h3>
                            <h1 style="text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #2A1057;" class="typed">Code your bot to the next level</h1>
                        <span class="typed-cursor">|</span>
                        <br><a href="404error/index.html"><img src="img/robo.gif" height="250" width="230"</a> <p> Click me for information!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The actual code for the robot is this

```
<a href="404error/index.html"><img src="img/robo.gif" height="250" width="230"</a> <p> Click me for information!</p>
```

The gif constantly loops... Can someone give me a code to make it stop? For some reason this isn't on w3schools or stackoverflow, Thank you! :)

Comment: It certainly is on StackOverflow. Similar questions have been asked many times. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171075/how-to-stop-an-animated-gif-from-looping . And FYI, none of the images load on your website.

Comment: Yeah the images aren't updated yet, That's why I put "there is an image there". Never the less Thank you for linking me in the right direction, much obliged!