# How to use after effect on website?

Tags: html, css, animation, after-effects

I'm learning after effect for animate a typography logo for my website. What format do I have to save and how can I integrate that in the HTML code?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Ps: if you know better way to animate a font logo it will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use after effect. If you want to make your website dynamic you can use JavaScript or with CSS animations and transitions. I think you have to delete this question.

Comment: How can I do this https://dribbble.com/shots/2354342-Craft-Fig-Studio with css?

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/xOgyjB

Comment: That work only if I've a linear font with only stroke to fill. If I need to animate something that isn't a line that can't work.

Comment: I don't know anything about your logo, I dropped that example so you can see how it is possible to animate logos with HTML, CSS and JS

Comment: I posted that question because I saw that i can't animate a logo with css and js only. Can I simply create an animation with after effect, save that as a gif and use it in my website?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why everyone is downvoting this...

All you need to do is turn your After Effects composition into a gif and place it in an `<img>` tag. You can [search this on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20create%20a%20gif%20after%20effects&oq=how%20to%20create%20a%20gif%20af).

Example: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/29591/screenshots/2354342/studio.gif

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I stop the loop with after affect in a gif? Can I control number of repeat times of my gif with css or JS?

Comment: @user2996092 Yep! Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jkovzels/75kg0tz1/ You can "fiddle" with this code (excuse the pun haha)

Comment: Oh and here's the question for it on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171075/how-to-stop-an-animated-gif-from-looping

Comment: Thanks guys for your help :)

Comment: Using gif for web animation is professional or a bad escape for someone like me that can't animate with js?

Comment: For simple animations we use JavaScript, but there is absolutely nothing wrong with using GIFs for more complex animations, like that example you gave is virtually impossible in JavaScript

Comment: I asked it because using gif in a website remind me when I'm tryed to animate forumfree website with bm's gifs in 90s' :D

Comment: Yeah definitely use JS for UI animations. We try to not talk about websites in the 90s xD