# How to prevent GIFs from running in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, gif

I'd like to use a gif as a logo of my app, but when I put the gif inside material UI Avatar or img it keeps looping forever.

How can I limit the loops to 1?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a code sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: edit it in photoshop, and set it to only play once in the timelime - that should do the trick right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop an animated gif from looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171075/how-to-stop-an-animated-gif-from-looping)