# Display the first frame of gif image inside a web page

Tags: javascript, html, gif

I have a web page that displays `.gif` images, I want to display only the first frame of the `.gif` (without animation) and I don't have a still version of it.

Is this possible?

UPDATE :

I want to make this on the client side. I don't have access to server (i.e) the server gives me `.gif` images and I want to display the first frame on my web page. Maybe there is a solution using javascript or css.

Comment: Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: If not, you could use this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062229/animated-gif-in-html5-canvas (i.e., you have quite the opposite problem as the OP there)

Comment: Don't tag it "PHP" if you can't work on server side. I retagged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use a JavaScript canvas as pointed out by Boldewyn in comments.

If that doesn't work out, I think you will have to do it server side. One tool that can do this is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). However, that needs to be present on your server and PHP needs to be able to access it.

Command line usage:

```
convert 'image.gif[0]' singleframe.gif
```

I'm sure PHP's ImageMagick extension can do this as well.