# How to play gif inside canvas in HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, gif

I want to play animated GIF file inside a HTML Canvas. I have used the code below but it is not working.

What is wrong with the code?

```
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawingCanvas');
if(drawingCanvas.getContext) 
{
    var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgObj = new Image();

    imgObj.onload = function () 
    {       
        context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, 1024, 600);
    }
    imgObj.src='HTML Images/Spell Bee/images/mainscreen.gif';
}
```

Comment: Is that image path correct? You should avoid using spaces in your url's but if you have to you need to replace them with '%20'.

Comment: I tried by removing spaces also.stil no difference

Comment: Look at the answer I posted. You should be able to do it that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated GIF in HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062229/animated-gif-in-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot as canvas doesn't provide any methods to deal with animated gifs. You should split gif into single frames then create a [spritesheet](http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog_media/sprite_movement/images/gb_walk.png) and animate it copying current frame.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually decode the GIF with JavaScript and write the frames to canvas. Check http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/

Comment: Update : the most relevant is to use the fork from buzzfeed : https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js. They fork the project @forresto  quoted, and added some basic functions.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that [answers your question](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/40515.aspx). Basically, when you add an animated gif to a canvas element it displays the exact state the image is at when it's included. So, as rezoner says, you need to create a spritesheet and animate it using javascript.