# How to use gif image inside html5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, gif

I've been searching all day to use gif image inside html5 canvas can't find a useful article in it,is there any way I could use gif image inside canvas. I'm in position to use a gif image inside a canvas but it doesn't changes it loads loads the first frame only and how to play the gif image completely or is there any way I could use gif formatted image inside a 
canvas.

Comment: ["You cannot as canvas doesn't provide any methods to deal with animated gifs. You should split gif into single frames then create a spritesheet and animate it copying current frame."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276594/how-to-play-gif-inside-canvas-in-html5)

Comment: thks man i am new to the concept canvas i don't know how to split gif into single frame and create a sprite sheet can u please explain it in detail

Comment: check [this](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/) site which offers a good js gif player which you can include in your canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [**jsgif: A GIF player in JavaScript**](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/)

> Unfortunately, the DOM doesn't expose individual frames of a GIF, so
>   this is done by downloading the GIF (with XMLHttpRequest), parsing it,
>   and drawing it on a .

Maybe you would take a look in the [**jsgif**](https://github.com/shachaf/jsgif) source code to find some ideas