# Call a single picture in GIF with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif

is it possible to get a single picture/frequence in an animated GIF with Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062229/animated-gif-in-html5-canvas

Comment: Check out this bookmarklet: http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/ and its source: https://github.com/shachaf/jsgif