# How to load GIF Image using Canvas in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, canvas, html5-canvas, gif

I'm using MacOS for testing it. I have `giflib` installed on my mac as per the documentation mentioned in [Canvas NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) .

I'm able to serve Images perfectly with canvas, but I'm unable to serve GIFs to the browser using Canvas. There are no error logs as well.

Here is my code:

```
   app.get('/media', function(req, res) {

    
    const { createCanvas, loadImage, giflib } = require('canvas')

    const canvas = createCanvas(600, 400)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


    const imagePath = loadImage('https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png')
    const gifPath = loadImage('https://www.hubspot.com/hubfs/Smiling%20Leo%20Perfect%20GIF.gif')

    gifPath.then((image) => { 
        // do something with image

        canvas.toBuffer((err2, buf) => {
            if (err2) {
                console.log("To Buffer Error>>>>>>", err2)
            }
            else
            {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
                res.end(buf, 'binary');
            }        

        }, 'image/gif', { quality: 0.95 })
    

    }).catch(err => {
            console.log('oh no!', err)
    })


})
```

The code works if I use `imagePath` and `mimeType` as `image/png`.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348567/14475852)

Comment: does this help - maybe a little more work but could work: https://jeremybouny.fr/en/articles/server_side_canvas_node/

Comment: I don't use NodeJS so you tell me: Is it not possible in Node to create an `<image>` element and set your GIF as `.src` and have browser display the GIF? If that's possible then you could also create a `<canvas>` element and draw the GIF pixels to it. Also there is a difference between drawing a GIF and drawing an **Animated GIF** (no multiple frames in `<canvas>` only the first frame). Maybe Node's Canvas doesn't understand GIF format. Do you currently get any error message (in console) about problem loading a GIF? And the error doesn't happen when you load a PNG?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot handle the animated gif with a single canvas.
You should either

- create an animated canvas as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180164/11009351 if you want to modify the image
- or simply write the image as a byte stream as follows

  ```
    const http = require("http");

    const express = require("express");
    const request = require("request");

    const app = express();
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(8080);

    app.get("/media", function (req, res) {
      const x = request(
        "https://www.hubspot.com/hubfs/Smiling%20Leo%20Perfect%20GIF.gif"
      );
      x.pipe(res);
    });
  ```

Comment: But I would have to save each frame in temp folder, make modifications & then merge everything together into a gif? Is there a better way?

Comment: I may recommend you to save and edit the gif with another npm package, then stream by using the second method using fs. You may check https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-on-gif if embedding a text is enough for you.

Comment: Not only text, I need to add shapes and Logos as well