# discord.js gif profile html

Tags: javascript, html, api, gif

discord.js is it possible to make a gif profile through html, help to implement it.
`I tried using base64:gif, but nothing came out`
all my attempts were unsuccessful, it was empty profile.gif
I have no idea how this can be implemented.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched?

Comment: I tried, antimatter15, and encoder, and base64:gif, but the same result everywhere, empty gif file. I also tried using html and used code from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234696/how-to-put-a-gif-with-canvas I see a gif on the site localhost:3000/profile.gif , and when I try to send a link via message.channel.send an attachment, an empty gif file also appears

Comment: [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and _show_ the results. More complete questions will attract good answers. Short incomplete questions that require people to attempt to reproduce what you are doing will likely be ignored. Assume you are describing your problem to a colleague who doesn't know your domain.